# Ending REPL server without having instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, read-eval-print-loop

If you don't run a script via command line, node enters the REPL mode automatically. I want to exit the REPL mode. The [REPLServer](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) class has a `close` method but I can't call it because I don't have access to the instance returned by [repl.start](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options) which node uses internally (node.js line 142) to realize its REPL mode. How can I exit the REPL mode though?

Outline from node.js line 142:

```
// If -i or --interactive were passed, or stdin is a TTY.
if (process._forceRepl || NativeModule.require('tty').isatty(0)) {
  // REPL
  var opts = {
    useGlobal: true,
    ignoreUndefined: false
  };
  if (parseInt(process.env['NODE_NO_READLINE'], 10)) {
    opts.terminal = false;
  }
  if (parseInt(process.env['NODE_DISABLE_COLORS'], 10)) {
    opts.useColors = false;
  }
  var repl = Module.requireRepl().start(opts); // <<< line 142
  repl.on('exit', function() {
    process.exit();
  });

} else {
  // Read all of stdin - execute it.
  process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

  var code = '';
  process.stdin.on('data', function(d) {
    code += d;
  });

  process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    process._eval = code;
    evalScript('[stdin]');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit REPL via your program by doing:

```
repl.rli.close();
```

This is what the [REPL exit command](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L837) does when you enter `.exit`.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to exit from a REPL started with the `node` command. Here's a few:

1. `.exit`
2. `process.exit();`
3. `process.kill()`
4. `process.kill(process.pid);`

Since you're using a terminal, you can also send a `SIGINT` by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice.